# Creating a list when parsing a file using Cassava in Haskell

Tags: csv, haskell

I'm able to parse my csv file using the following code from Data.Csv:

```
valuesToList :: Foo -> (Int, Int)
valuesToList (Foo a b) = (a,b)

loadMyData :: IO ()
loadMyData = do
  csvData <- BL.readFile "mydata.csv"
  case decodeByName csvData of
        Left err -> putStrLn err 
        Right (_, v) -> print $ V.toList $ V.map valuesToList v
```

When I run this I get the correct output on the screen. The problem I have is I'm not clear how to create a pure function so I can consume the contents of the list, as in:

```
let l = loadMyData
```

Where l is of type `[Int,Int]` I'm guessing it's because I'm in the IO Monad and I'm doing something hopelessly silly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm doing something hopelessly silly...

Yes, but worry not!

```
loadMyData = BL.readFile "mydata.csv"

processMyData :: String -> String
processMyData csvData = 
  case decodeByName csvData of
        Left err -> err 
        Right (_, v) -> show $ V.toList $ V.map valuesToList v

main = do
    csv <- loadMyData
    let output = processMyData csv
    print output
```

This way you separate the pure, "let" part from the impure loading part. This isn't Code Review (if you asked there, I could probably elaborate more), but I'd type the processing as `String -> Either String [Int, Int]` or something and keep the failure information in the type system.

```
processMyData csvData = 
  case decodeByName csvData of
        Left err -> Left err 
        Right (_, v) -> Right $ V.toList $ V.map valuesToList v
```

And that in turn could simply be (pardon me if I make a mistake somewhere, I'm *doing it live*):

```
processMyData = fmap (V.toList . V.map valuesToList) . decodeByName
```

That should work because of [how the `Functor` instance for `Either`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5195254/understanding-how-either-is-an-instance-of-functor) is constructed.

---

Oh, and also use [`Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Control-Applicative.html) for bonus style points:

```
main = do
    output <- processMyData <$> loadMyData
    print output
```

(in case you don't understand that example, `(<$>)` is infix `fmap`, but that's not stricly necessary; hence *bonus*)

Comment: So now the compiler gives me this: Couldn't match type `BL.ByteString' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: String
      Actual type: BL.ByteString
    In the first argument of `processMyData', namely `csv'
    In the expression: processMyData csv
    In an equation for `output': output = processMyData csv

Comment: @AnthonyW I'm sorry for any mistakes I might have made. This should give you enough to get it to work, though

Comment: yep. the type of signature of processMyData is ByteString -> String

Comment: and I'd like to get ByteString -> [(Int,Int)]

Comment: @AnthonyW [You might find this useful](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=ByteString+-%3E+String). Sorry for not being there to help you yesterday, I had just enough time to write the answer. If you've managed (or manage to fix the problems in the future), edit my answer or add your own!